# Make wordpress custom anchor links scroll below fixed header

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, anchor

I've been stuck on this for days.
I cannot figure it out.

I have a Wordpress page that is using custom anchor links on the content pages at the client's request. When an anchor link is clicked from the nav, the content flows behind my fixed header. I need this content to appear below the fixed header, so that it is not cut off.

I have tried plugins, css, straight jquery, you name it. 
I cannot make this work.

Site is here, and if you click on one of the dropdown nav links, you'll see what i mean.

http://www.zachkeller.net/cp_site/about#company

Please help. I'm getting desperate here.

Comment: I m not getting wat u want?? is ther issue in menu dropdown or footer links ..Plz elaborate your query ??

Comment: I want the main body content to laod underneath the header, so that the title bar and first few lines of content are not sitting behind the header.

Comment: When an anchor link is clicked, the content loads from the top of the window, sitting underneath the header. I need it to load underneath the header so that no content is cut off.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Here is a way to do it with jQuery. Since I didn't test it, so there might be some error. Let me know:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var scrollOffset = $('.header-wrapper').outerWidth();
    $('#nav a').on('click', function(e) {
        var regex = new RegExp(/\#(.*)/),
        url = $(this).attr('href'),
        search = url.match(regex);

        if(search === null || search[1] === '') {
            return true;
        }

        var element = $('#' + search[1]);
        if(element.length) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var scrollTo = element.offset().top - scrollOffset - 20;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: scrollTo
            }, 'fast');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

**OLD COMMENT**

There are two things I need to say:

1. The way you added custom anchor links are wrong. Instead of the URL `http://www.zachkeller.net/cp_site/approach#method` it should be `http://www.zachkeller.net/cp_site/approach/#method`. Note the trailing slash.
2. Now for your issue, a quick CSS hack might get you going:

   ```
   .blog-inside > div {
       padding-top: 110px;
   }
   ```

If that doesn't what you want, then let me know. I will give a more comprehensive jQuery solution.

Comment: This is somewhat better, however, it is creating large unsightly gaps between my divs. http://www.zachkeller.net/cp_site/approach/#insights

Comment: @eloist I've edited the answer to suite you. Now you can remove the CSS and try the JS solution.

Comment: I've implemented the javascript, but it's doing some weird stuff. Some links don't work, and it doesn't really scroll to where it needs to be. Not sure what to do from ehre